# What is the minimum Nugets footprint for Sitecore FakeDB tests?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I started with standard `Sitecore.Kernel` and `Sitecore.Nexus`. Sitecore gives pretty descriptive error message here, so I added `DependencyInjection` as well. It brings lots of dependencies and they are not shown in config belo. As you can see I use `*.NoReferences` version of Sitecore packages to control dependencies.

```xml
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.FakeDb" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Kernel.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Nexus.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

After that I stuck. I got an error that did not provide much clue on what is missed:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
    at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
    at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
    at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
    at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
    at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, Boolean assert)
    at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert)
    at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name)
    at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name)
    at Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase(String databaseName)
    at Sitecore.FakeDb.Db..ctor(String databaseName)
    at Sitecore.FakeDb.Db..ctor()
    at SitecoreTests.Class1.HowToCreateSimpleItem() in C:\prog\temp\SitecoreTests\SitecoreTests\Class1.cs:line 17
```

So, what is missing to make simple Fake DB test work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying all packages referenced as dependencies in full `Sitecore.Kernel` I ended with this setup:

```xml
<packages>
  <package id="Lucene.Net" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.FakeDb" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Kernel.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Logging.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Nexus.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

It is clear now that Sitecore cannot start without `Sitecore.Logging`.

`Lucene.Net` required as well, but error for it is much more helpfull:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Lucene.Net, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

P.S. If you do not care about referencing extra DLLs you can add only two packages to make you test work - `Sitecore.Nexus` (without `.NoReferences`) and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of packages I used in the [Fortis](https://github.com/Fortis-Collection/fortis/blob/master/src/Fortis.Tests/packages.config) unit test project:

```xml
<packages>
  <package id="AutoFixture" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Lucene.Net" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="3.0.50813.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="1.0.20105.408" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="1.0.20105.408" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NSubstitute" version="1.10.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="RazorGenerator.Mvc" version="2.4.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Abstractions.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Analytics.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Buckets.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.ContentSearch.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.FakeDb" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.FakeDb.AutoFixture" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.FakeDb.NSubstitute" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.FakeDb.Serialization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Kernel.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Logging.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Nexus.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.0.12" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="xunit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Also make sure you have your `/App_Config/Include` folder setup for your config: [Here is the Fortis one](https://github.com/Fortis-Collection/fortis/tree/master/src/Fortis.Tests/App_Config/Include)